# How can I print these values (see description) in a table?

Tags: php

Maybe this question is really simple but I can't find any answers on internet and I'm a PHP noob.

how can I print this:

```
[{"1":{"key":"Aansturing","value":"AAN\/UIT"}},{"1":{"key":"Maximale output","value":"6 W"}},{"1":{"key":"Product categorie","value":"Selecteerbare I OUT"}},{"1":{"key":"Output stroom","value":"350 mA \/ 700 mA"}}]
```

In

Comment: show the expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$jsonString = '[{"1":{"key":"Aansturing","value":"AAN\/UIT"}},{"1":{"key":"Maximale output","value":"6 W"}},{"1":{"key":"Product categorie","value":"Selecteerbare I OUT"}},{"1":{"key":"Output stroom","value":"350 mA \/ 700 mA"}}]';
$jsonData = json_decode($jsonString, TRUE);
?>
<table border>
    <tr>
        <th>Key</th>
        <th>Value</th>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach ($jsonData as $oneRowData): ?>
        <?php foreach ($oneRowData as $oneRow): ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $oneRow['key'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $oneRow['value'] ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks Shadab! This works great!

Answer (score 0):

By print, I am assuming you want to be able to echo individual items in that JSON dataset. If so, you need to use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
$json = '[{"1":{"key":"Aansturing","value":"AAN\/UIT"}},{"1":{"key":"Maximale output","value":"6 W"}},{"1":{"key":"Product categorie","value":"Selecteerbare I OUT"}},{"1":{"key":"Output stroom","value":"350 mA \/ 700 mA"}}]'

$ar = json_decode($json);
```

You can then access your elements like this:

```
echo $ar[0];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! With your answer and the answer of Shadab my table is looking good now ;)